# Unable to access the internet, although WiFi is connected

Tags: wireless

Problem: as described

I understand that there have been multiple questions pertaining to this issue, but so far none of them have seemed to work for me. It’s so frustrating, could anyone please help?

The command `“sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces”` yields the following output:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I think that there might be something to do with the Kernel IP routing table - it’s empty. How do I go about fixing this?